# Javascript for loop not looping with concatenated string

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<div id="this1"></div>
```

JS

```
var total = 5;
for (var i=0; i<total; i++){
    var id = "this" + i.toString();
    var s= document.getElementById("this1");
    s.innerHTML += id;
    s.innerHTML += "<br/>";
}
```

Output

```
this0
this1
this2
this3
this4
```

What I'd like is to change the element selector to the var id.

```
var s= document.getElementById(id);
```

When I do this the loop iterates once and stops. If I change the for loops i to 1,2,3,etc and match the html div id with that IE:

html

```
<div id="this3"></div>
```

js

```
for (var i=3; i<total; i++){
```

output

```
this3
```

I get one successful output, as I should. However, starting the iterator at 0 I get 1 loop and that's it.

Is there something fundamental I'm not noticing in my half awakeness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your loop is 0 based so you need an id of this0 otherwise it will throw an exception when you try and do `.innerHtml` on something that is undefined.

```
<div id="this0"></div>
<div id="this1"></div>
<div id="this2"></div>
<div id="this3"></div>
<div id="this4"></div>

var total = 5;
for (var i=0; i<total; i++){
    var id = "this" + i;
    var s= document.getElementById(id);
    s.innerHTML += id;
    s.innerHTML += "<br/>";
}
```

Also you don't need `toString` js knows to convert it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/75jah/

Comment: Awesome, I'm not used to writing JS, that fixed it perfectly, I can close this in a couple minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a corresponding element (`<div id="this0">` if you start at `i = 0`), then you will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` and the script will halt.